# meteor subscribe/publish with parameter return 0

Tags: javascript, meteor

i studying subscribe and publish now.
this is my subscribe.js on client

```
var userhandle = null;

Deps.autorun(function () {
    userhandle = Meteor.subscribe('user', 1);
    if(userhandle.ready()){
    console.log("ready");
    }

});
```

and this my publish.js on server

```
Meteor.publish('user', function (amount) {

    return Users.find({
        limit: amount
    });
});
```

i wish i can publish "Users" data as much i need.

after i run this, nothing error, and i do

```
Users.find().fetch()
```

on browser console, but it return 0 length
Why this happen? 
how to make this works?

Update :
Iam not use meteor.users
I just use simply collection
Users = new Meteor.collection("USER");

Comment: The users collection from the `accounts` packages is `Meteor.users`. Where are you defining a `Users` collection?

Comment: I am not use Meteor.users just simply collection

Comment: This could be a big security problem. Meteor's accounts package uses the reliable, secure protocol called [Secure Remote Password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol). Are you transferring or storing passwords in cleartext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find` query in the publish function is not formed correctly - if you're specifying options, you need a query object, even if it's an empty one:

```
return Users.find({}, {
    limit: amount
});
```

Give that a go.